# "Complex located in the street", due to messed up with CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers

I need to combine two .shp files from two different sources.
First one is [20 Expanded parcels during 2012-2017 by MVP-CA](https://www.beijingcitylab.com/data-released-1/data1-20/), which I use as the base layer. The second one is a point layer of the [Housing complexes of Beijing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c64rn8fyxb0voym/Housing%20Complexes.rar?dl=0).
The problem is the CRS of two layers are different. `EPSG:4326,WGS:84` for the first layer and

[image]

for the second layer. **I have enabled the 'on the fly' option**.
However, when I open two layers, all the complexes located in the street instead of parcels, where they are supposed to locate. I guess it's due to the contradiction of projection system, but I don't know how to fix it. Since I know directly change projection system can be problematic.

[image]

---

Update:
   I know there is an intentional deviation added to the GPS by the Chinese mapping authority to "keep secret of nation". Could this be the source of my problem?

Comment: You are surely right with the "secret of nation". Try a `+towgs84` value different from all zero.

Comment: None of the layers are in `EPSG:4326`. Have a look to this website to inspect the `*.prj` files : http://prj2epsg.org/search.

Comment: Both shapefiles have .prj files, but they seem to be wrong for me.

Comment: Hi,@AndreJ, wrong about what?

Comment: @wiltomap. Thank you for comment, but I was a little bit confusing. I check the CRS in QGIS, and the parcel layer is in `selected CRS (EPSG:4326, WGS:84)` though not `project CRS`. I don't quite know their difference. And if they are indeed different. Should I just use the converter to make them identity (in arbitrary  EPSG ?) and replace the original .prj file?

Comment: If I load the files into QGIS, and a Natural Earth border polygon, both your files don't align with the chinese border.